# Is it safe to force unwrap `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!` in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm not sure if `urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)` could be an empty array or not, so I'm not sure if it is a good idea to make the following `FileManager` extension, can someone give me some advice? Thanks.

```swift
import Foundation

extension FileManager {
    var documentDirectory: URL {
        // Is it safe to force unwrap in this specific case❓
        urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    }
}

// use case
FileManager.default.documentDirectory
```

Comment: On macOS it is allowed to remove the Documents folder, not sure about iOS, so then you would need to return an optional